# Blending problem - calculate prices of a product given an increase in profits

Tags: ampl

new to AMPL.

In a blending problem, I have solved a model by maximizing profit.

Furthermore, I'm trying to calculate what the unit price of a given amount of product has to be, in order to increase my profits with a certain percentage.

Is it possible to do this directly in run. ?

By applying "let" i'm able to change the amount of product available, but i'm struggling figuring out how to set the price of the product as a variable? How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what you're trying to do here? It's not clear to me what you're asking. [This guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might be helpful.

Comment: Yes ofcourse! Let's say we have a blending problem with two suppliers (S1,S2), which can blend different end-products by combining different oil types (O1,O2), wheras each of the suppliers have different amounts of oil-types available at different and have different purchase prices. Per now, i've made a profit-maximizing model calculating in costs(purchase price) and sellprice of the end-products. This has given me a profit = X. Then, a third supplier arises (S3) with a total of 100 oiltype O1 available - is there any way for me to model what the purchase price of this oil per unit(an unknown)

Comment: .. has to be for my original profit (X) to increase by for example 5%*? (X*1.05) - maybe by coding in run. ? When I try to enter the price as a variable (for instance a) in the data file, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you're trying to do here.

One is to solve a modified version of the problem with a requirement that the profit be at least X% better than the previous version of the problem. This can be done as follows:

- Solve the original version of the problem
- Set a param `profit_0` equal to the profit from the old problem.
- Modify the constraints on the problem as appropriate
- Change the objective function, so it's now "maximise Supplier 3's price".
- Re-solve the problem with a new constraint that the profit in the new solution be at least as good as `1.05*profit_0` or whatever the requirement is.

The other is to treat *some* prices as fixed and others as variables. Probably the simplest way to do this is define them all as variables but then constrain some of them to fixed values.

Coding these in AMPL isn't too hard, and I'll give an example of the syntax below. Unfortunately, the fact that you're multiplying (variable price) by (variable quantity bought) to find your costs means you end up with a quadratic constraint, which many solvers will reject.

In this example I've used Gecode, which isn't ideal for this kind of problem (in particular, it requires all variables be integer) but does at least allow for quadratic constraints:

```
reset;
option solver gecode;
# all the "integer" constraints in this example are there because
# gecode won't accept non-integer variables; ideally they wouldn't
# be there.

# To keep the demo simple, we assume that we are simply buying
# a single ingredient from suppliers and reselling it, without
# blending considerations.

param ingredients_budget;
# the maximum we can spend on buying ingredients

set suppliers;

param max_supply{suppliers};
# maximum amount each supplier has available

var prices{suppliers} integer >= 0;
# the amount charged by each supplier - in fact we want to treat
# some of those as var and some as constant, which we'll do by
# fixing some of the values.

param fixed_prices{suppliers} default -1;
# A positive value will be interpreted as "fix price at this value";
# negative will be interpreted as variable price.

s.t. fix_prices{s in suppliers: fixed_prices[s] > 0}:
    prices[s] = fixed_prices[s];

param selling_price;

var quantity_bought{s in suppliers} >= 0, <= max_supply[s] integer;

var quantity_sold integer;
s.t. max_sales: quantity_sold = sum{s in suppliers} quantity_bought[s];

var input_costs integer;
s.t. defineinputcosts: input_costs = sum{s in suppliers} quantity_bought[s]*prices[s];

s.t. enforcebudget: input_costs <= ingredients_budget;

var profit integer;
s.t. defineprofit: profit = quantity_sold*selling_price - input_costs;

maximize OF1: profit;

data;
param ingredients_budget := 1000;

set suppliers :=
S1
S2
;

param max_supply :=
S1 100
S2 0
;

param fixed_prices :=
S1 120
;

param selling_price := 150;

model;

print("Running first case with nothing available from S2");

solve;


display profit;
display quantity_bought;
display quantity_sold;

param profit_0;
let profit_0 := profit;

param increase_factor = 0.05;

let max_supply["S2"] := 100;

s.t. improveprofit: profit >= (1+increase_factor)*profit_0;

maximize OF2: prices["S2"];
objective OF2;

print("Now running to increase profit.");
solve;


display profit;
display quantity_bought;
display quantity_sold;
display prices["S2"];
```

Another option is to use [AMPL's looping commands](https://ampl.com/NEW/loop1.html) to run the same problem repeatedly but changing the relevant price value each time, to see which price values give an acceptable profit. If you do this, you don't need to declare price as a var, just make it a param and use "let" to change it between scenarios. This will avoid the quadratic constraint and allow you to use MIP solvers like CPLEX and Gurobi.

You could also ask on the Operations Research SE, where you might get some better answers than I can give you.